# Layer is not being display even though it was assigned high z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing an issue with a div not being displayed when it is toggled from `display: none;` to `display: block;`

HTML:

```
<div class="menus-container" style="display: block; top: 50px; height: 277px;">
.. some pretent content, which shows up in another place on the website ...
</div>
```

Which is toggled by js by a plugin JS which is minified so I cannot list the js, but I see in the developer toolbar that the style changes work.

I see that it has a height, I see that it has a width and a z-index of about 99999.To be sure I assigned in the developer tool bars all parent elements as well an `z-index: 999 !important;`

Still that div wont show up... any ideas? If you want to look at the example follow this link (redacted) - it only happens at a width of less than 850px.

Comment: Make sure it has content or else you will not tell that it is there.

Comment: Thanks, yes there is some content in there. I have added some pretend content for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't a z-index issue, it's that the menu is appearing outside of its parent, the `header` element, which has overflow set to hidden. Setting the overflow to visible reveals the menu. You'll want to do some other things too, like give the menu a solid background color so it's easier to read.

```
<header class="main-header collapsed-gallery-page-menu" style="overflow: visible;">
```